# Problem with \titleprefixword

Tags: macros, indexing, songs

I'm trying to make a songbook with `Songs` Package. The songs are in Spanish and I want to use the `\titleprefixword` macro to avoid sorting my song titles starting with the articles (El, La, Los, Las).

This is the code and I think eveything is correct but it's obviously not because it's not working:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \includeonlysongs{2}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}

\titleprefixword{El}
\titleprefixword{La}
\titleprefixword{Los}
\titleprefixword{Las}
\titleprefixword{Un}
\titleprefixword{Una}

\authsepword{y}
\authbyword{por}
\authignoreword{Desconocido}

\ifchorded
  \newcommand{\stopchords}{\chordsoff}
  \newcommand{\resumechords}{\chordson}
\else
  \newcommand{\stopchords}{}
  \newcommand{\resumechords}{}
\fi

%\makeatletter
%\xpatchcmd{\SB@@@beginsong}
%  {\SB@addtoindexes\songtitle}
%  {\SB@addtoindexes{\songtitle\ifx\songauthors\empty\else\ (\songauthors)\fi}}
%  {}{}
%\makeatother

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
%\indexsongsas{titleidx}{\thepage}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{cbauth}
\newscripindex{scripidx}{cbscrip}

\begin{document}

\showindex{Índice Completo de Canciones y Temas}{titleidx}

\songsection{Himnario de la Iglesia Reformada en Venezuela}
\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx,scripidx}

 \beginsong{La Cruz Excelsa}[
  by={Isaac Watts},
  sr={Números 21:4-9; Marcos 15:1-47; Romanos 5:6-11; Filipenses 2:1-13; Salmos 34:2; 1 Corintios 1:17-31; 1 Pedro 2:19-25},
  ititle={(salvación)},
  ititle={(cruz)},
  ititle={(entrega)},
  ititle={(sacrificio)},
  ititle={(muerte de Cristo)}]

\beginverse  
\[D]La cruz ex\[^\gtab{Dmaj9}{200220}]celsa al \[Em]con\[A]tem\[D]plar
\[D]Do Cristo a\[G]llí \[D/F#]por \[E7]mí mu\[A]rió,
\[D]De todo \[Dmaj9]cuanto es\[Em]ti\[A]mo a\[D]quí,
\[D]Lo más pre\[G]cio\[D/F#]so \[Em]es \[A]su a\[D]mor.
\endverse
\beginverse 
^No busco \[Dmaj9]gloria ^ni ^ho^nor
^Sino en la ^cruz ^de \[Bm7]mi ^Se^ñor,
^Las cosas ^que me en^can^tan ^más
^Las sacri^fi^co ^por ^su a^mor.
\endverse
\stopchords
\beginverse 
De su cabeza, manos, pies,
Preciosa sangre allí corrió;
Corona vil de espinas fue
La que Jesús por mí llevó.
\endverse
\beginverse 
El mundo entero no será
Dádiva digna de ofrecer.
Amor tan grande, sin igual,
En cambio, exige todo el ser.
\endverse
\resumechords
\endsong

\beginscripture{Salmos 34:2}
\Acolon Mi alma se gloría en el Señor;
\Bcolon lo oirán los humildes y se alegrarán.
\endscripture
\end{songs}


\showindex{Índice de Autores y Compositores}{authidx}
\showindex{Índice de Referencias Bíblicas}{scripidx}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to make it work!?

Comment: I have had the same issue for a while. I just got the newest version (songs 3.0) and it still isn't fixed.

Comment: Ok, I did find a work around. You can manually add the song to the index. So just after the `\beginsong` command, add
`\indextitleentry[titleidx]{Cruz Excelsa, La}`

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with `authsepword` and `authignoreword`. Moving them just before `\begin{document}` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug that `\titleprefixword` is completely ignored by the songs package (even after upgrading to version 3.0). However, the fix is actually pretty simple. You have to modify the script that creates the indices: **songidx.lua**. Change the line

```
prelist = { A=true, THE=true}
```

to add all your desired prefixes, all  in capitals, e.g.,

```
prelist = { A=true, THE=true, EL=true, LA=true}
```